# D3.csv accessor function for loop

Tags: javascript, csv, for-loop, d3.js, accessor

I have a csv with many rows and I want to manipulate the data in accessor function before visualizing it. In every example I have seen so far this function returns something like that:

```
return {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3
    ...
  };
```

An I want to use for loop to avoid writing every key-value pair manually like this (I know it's not valid but it represents the idea)

```
d3.csv("data/vitoAgeScrpdNew3x.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    for (var i=0;i<d3.keys(d).length; i++){
    d3.keys(d)[i]: +d3.values(d)[i]
    }
  };
}
```

How to make this properly? Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

Tried for..in. Returns just one property

```
for(var prop in d) {
return {
  prop: d[prop]
    }
 };
```

Comment: what is your input data, and what is your desired output? your `for..in` won't work since you have the `return` statement inside it, it will break the `for` loop right away.

Comment: Oops, I knew that something was wrong. That makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create and fill with values an object you want to return beforehand, i.e.:

```
d3.csv("data/vitoAgeScrpdNew3x.csv", function(d) {
  myObj = {};
  for (var i=0;i<d3.keys(d).length; i++) {
    myObj[ d3.keys(d)[i] ] = +d3.values(d)[i];
  }
  return myObj;

}
```

Comment: Just return an object. Great! :) I had such a mindblock, you literally saved me!